# SoQL returns 'a1Xb00000008xB7EAI' for person's name. How do I get the text?

Tags: apex, soql

These fields contain a person name in the usual format, but SOQL returns Id of the record as strings. Can the SOQL query results display this as the actual name? Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you include your soql query ? You've queried the relation which is the ID of the corresponding record. To query fields you'll have to use the relation to transcend into the parent/child fields.

Comment: In addition to the @Samuel De Rycke's reply I have noticed that if you are not populating the `Name` field of an object when inserting it by default it set the `Id` value of the record for the `Name`. Then when you are retrieving the data back, Name field will be having `Id` value.

Comment: Thanks. If you add as an answer I will accept it. I was using K__Resource__c and I needed to use K__Resource__r.Name

Answer (score 7):

This field have to be lookup.
Lookup and Master-Detail are specific kind of field.
From user perspective they are displayed as a name of parent object.
But from code prespective those are Ids of parents objects.

If you want access name of parent object by SOQL you have to reference Name field on Parent object.

for custom object it will look like

```
SELECT ParentObjectLookup__r.Name FROM ChildObject.
```

'__r' construction allows you access parent object

In case of standard object you have to use same logic but construcyion is diffrent.
For example thats how get Account Name from opportunity

```
SELECT Acccount.Name FROM Opportunity
```

Please read some more about SOQL to better understand relations in Salesforce .